# How to get data from BW08 Vehicle Tracker (GPS) using Node js and socket io on Web?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a BW-08 Vehicle Tracker and i want to integrate with web application using node-js.
I will be thankful if someone give some clue or hints.

Answer (score 2):

Here are few app links which can help

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/gps-tracking-maps-socket-io
- https://github.com/freshworkstudio/gps-tracking-nodejs

Comment: another help link https://github.com/viettranx/tracking-location-socketio

Comment: Thanks @flik for the tips